# Change scale values by Lerp?

Tags: unity, scale, lerp

How to change the scale values of object by using Lerp. from 0 to 0.01722f and reveals later ?

```
public Vector3 vp1;
public bool checkers;

void Start()
{
    checkers = false;
    vp1 = gameObject.transform.localScale; // (0.01722F,0.01722F,0.01722F)
}

void Update()
{

    if (checkers == true)
    {
            vp1 = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), vp1, 0.2f);
    }
     else
    {
            vp1 = Vector3.Lerp(vp1, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 0.2f);
    }

}
```

Comment: Vector3 are a struct, they are passed by value and not reference. you need to pass it back to the gameObject transform with: transform.localScale = vp1; at the end of your update.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you. Could you script it please.

Comment: @OmarGuendeli post that as an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted. :)

Comment: Yes, Now I can understand what he meant. anyway. Still the lerp not doing his job !! There is no smooth or good transfer of scale values !! here is the [new script](https://pastebin.com/37EQhmr2). It's from the lerp or from me ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you changed, and describe what behavior you're seeing, and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: OK. I have the solution for scale lerp. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway. Here how to solve the scale lerp.

```
public Vector3 vp1,vp2,vp3;
public bool checkers;

void Start()
{
  checkers = false;
  vp2 = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  vp3 = new Vector3(0.001722403f, 0.001722403f, 0.001722403f);
}

void Update()
{

    gameObject.transform.localScale = vp1;

  if (checkers == true)
  {
      vp1 = Vector3.Lerp(vp1, vp3, Time.deltaTime * 8f);
  }
   else
  {
      vp1 = Vector3.Lerp(vp1, vp2, Time.deltaTime * 20f);
  }

}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what you had to change and why that solves the problem.